# Como selecionar um radio através de outro?

Tags: javascript, html

Digamos que eu tenho 3 inputs do tipo 'radio' (A,B,C) e eu tenho outros dois 'radio'(X,Z) Logo de inicio os *radios* X,Z estarão **desabilitados** e só poderão ser auto-selecionados se o radio **B** ou **C** forem clicados, e se eu clicar no radio **A**, os radios(X,Z) devem voltar e ficar desabilitadas novamente.

Segue o código como exemplo, to querendo colocar tudo isso em JavaScrip (não sei se tem outra forma, mas o meu interesse seria JS):

```
<FORM>
   <fieldset><legend><font color="darkblue"> CAIXA 1 </font></legend>
      <input type="radio" id ="rada" name="planoSaud" />A
      <input type="radio" id="radb" name="planoSaud" />B
      <input type="radio" id="radc" name="planoSaud" />C
   </fieldset> 
</FORM>
<FORM>
   <fieldset><legend><font color="darkblue"> CAIXA 2 </font></legend>
      <input type="radio" id ="radx" name="planoSaud" />X
      <input type="radio" id="radz" name="planoSaud" />Z
   </fieldset>
</FORM>
```

Valeu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode adicionar um `eventListener` aos `radios` A, B e C. Adicione também `disabled="disabled"` aos `radios` X e Y para eles carregarem desabilitados:

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll("#rada, #radb, #radc");
for(x=0;x<els.length; x++){
   els[x].addEventListener("change", function() {

   if(this.id == 'rada'){
   }

   document.querySelector('#radx').disabled = document.querySelector('#radz').disabled = this.id == 'rada' ?
   true : false;

   if(this.id == 'rada'){
      document.querySelector('#radx').checked = document.querySelector('#radz').checked = false;
   }

  });
}
```

```html
<FORM>
   <fieldset><legend><font color="darkblue"> CAIXA 1 </font></legend>
      <input type="radio" id ="rada" name="planoSaud" />A
      <input type="radio" id="radb" name="planoSaud" />B
      <input type="radio" id="radc" name="planoSaud" />C
   </fieldset> 
</FORM>
<FORM>
   <fieldset><legend><font color="darkblue"> CAIXA 2 </font></legend>
      <input disabled="disabled" type="radio" id ="radx" name="planoSaud" />X
      <input disabled="disabled" type="radio" id="radz" name="planoSaud" />Z
   </fieldset>
</FORM>
```

Comment: Ali no caso quando eu clicar no Rad'B' e depois clicar no Rad'Z' por exemplo, e sem seguida eu clicar no Rad'A' o Rad'Z' é apenas desabilitado, teria como eu limpar ele, pois ele ainda fica como se estivesse selecionado.

Comment: @Ricksoz97 Resposta atualizada.

Comment: Teria algum outro método que poderia ser utilizando sem usar `querySelector`? devido a eu estar iniciando ainda a utilizar lógica de programação (tanto pra page web quanto pra software). Ai no caso eu estava utilizando em alguns exercícios o `document.getElementById('teste').disabled= false` e com o `querySelector`eu não estou conseguindo rodar ele direito no JS.

Comment: @Ricksoz97 Tem sim... peraí que vou fazer aqui e te mando

Comment: @Ricksoz97 Aí seria necessário criar um array com os ids dos radios A, B e C. Veja neste JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/62s22u65/